# How to get the innerHTML/innerText from a related node of a clicked element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

I would like to get a certain innerText from a clicked  element in a HTML document that I clicked.

The corresponding HTML looks something like this:

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Some title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="categories">
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.example2.com/1">
            <div>
                <img src="http://www.example.com/someSource">
                <span>First</span>
            </div>
            </a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="http://www.example2.com/1">
            <div>
                <img src="http://www.example.com/someSource">
                <span>Second</span>
            </div>
            </a>
        </li>

    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

A Javascript function should return either "First" or "Second" depending on the clicked link.

My basic idea is to add an event listener and use the returned event to get the content of the span element:

```
function(){
  document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var spanText= e.path[i].innerText; //Don't know how to assign i correctly
    return spanText;
    }, false);
}
```

My problem is that I don't know how to define *i* or if there is something more suitable than *.path[i]* to work with. Depending on whether I click the image or the text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Add the click events to the list items
- in the handler, retrieve the 'span' child and get its text

```js
var lis = document.querySelectorAll('.categories li');
lis.forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', onClick, false);
})

function onClick(e) {
  var li = e.currentTarget;
  var span = li.querySelector('span');
  console.log(span.innerText);
}
```

```html
<ul class="categories">
  <li>
    <a href="http://www.example2.com/1">
      <div>
        <img src="http://www.example.com/someSource">
        <span>First</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="http://www.example2.com/1">
      <div>
        <img src="http://www.example.com/someSource">
        <span>Second</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function init(){
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var link = e.target.closest('a');
  if(!link)return;
  e.preventDefault();
  var text = link.textContent;
  alert(text);

  return spanText;
  });
}

init();
```

Comment: What happens if the user clicks on the image?

Answer (score 0):

You can check what concrete element was clicked and then return its text. if you want to have some additional information - use `data-` attributes and read `target.dataset` to read it.

```js
  document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var target = e.target;

    if(target.tagName === 'SPAN') {
        console.log(target.innerText);  
        return target.innerText;
    }
    
  }, false);
```

```html
<ul class="categories">
        <li>
            <a href="#">
            <div>
                <img src="http://www.example.com/someSource">
                <span>First</span>
            </div>
            </a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#">
            <div>
                <img src="http://www.example.com/someSource">
                <span>Second</span>
            </div>
            </a>
        </li>

    </ul>
```

Comment: What happens if the user clicks on the image?

Comment: The check will not pass `if(target.tagName === 'SPAN'). What behavior you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I might have misread the question, but I think the OP wants a click on the *link* to return the word in the span. (ie. not a click on the span to return the word in the span).

Answer (score 0):

If the structure is consistent, then there will always be the same number of `<span>` elements as `<a>` elements.

Consequently, if you know the user just clicked on the second `<a>`, you'll know the `<span>` you need to return is the second `<span>`.

**Working Example:**

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll('li a');
var spans = document.querySelectorAll('li div span');

function getTextContent(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var linksArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(links);
    var index = linksArray.indexOf(this);
    console.log(spans[index].textContent);
}

links.forEach(function(link){
    link.addEventListener('click', getTextContent, false);
});
```

```html
<ul class="categories">
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.example2.com/1">
            <div>
                <img src="http://www.example.com/someSource">
                <span>First</span>
            </div>
            </a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="http://www.example2.com/1">
            <div>
                <img src="http://www.example.com/someSource">
                <span>Second</span>
            </div>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my bad language..

I'm late to reply.

Maybe it will help someone else;

```
window.addEventListener("click", (event) => { //dblclick    
  let div = event.target.innerText; // <-- the code you want
  window.onClick(div);
});
```

And..

```
function onClick(div) {
   console.log(`(Tıklandı-Clicked) innerText: ${div}`);
}
```

the code you want : `let div = event.target.innerText;`